# Is every transitive action conformal?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, conformal-geometry

Suppose that a Lie group $ G $ acts transitively on a manifold $ M $. If $ G $ is compact then we can equip $ M $ with a Riemannian metric with respect to which $ G $ acts by isometries.

What if $ G $ is noncompact? Can we equip $ M $ with a Riemannian metric with respect to which $ G $ acts by conformal transformations?

The first counter example that comes to mind is take $ G=E_2 $ the isometry group of the plane. Then take $ M $ to be the Moebius strip or the Klein bottle. $ G $ acts transitively on both these spaces. But I have no idea if the action is conformal (say with respect to the flat metric).

Comment: How would a rotation act on the Möbius strip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Take $G=\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ for $n \ge 3$ and consider the action on $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. If the action preserved the conformal class of a Riemannian metric $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$, then the stabilizer $H$ of a point $[v]$ would preserve the conformal class of the metric on the tangent space $T_{[v]}\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. But every linear transformation of $T_{[v]}\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ is induced by an element of $H$, so $H$ cannot preserve a conformal class when $n \ge 3$.

More generally, you can find lots of actions where the point-stabilizer is "too big" to respect a conformal class.

Comment: Could you explain more about your argument for why the action cannot be conformal? In particular the last step where you conclude that the stabilizer H cannot preserve a conformal class. For example what is the particular step in this argument that fails for the the circle (n=2)?

Comment: We have a homomorphism $H \to \mathrm{GL}(T_{[v]}\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{n-1})$ which turns out to be surjective but not injective. For the case $n=2$, we consider linear transformations of a $1$-dimensional vector space. This is just scaling by some number, so it preserves any conformal class (there is only one anyway).

Comment: To complete the argument, you need to see that $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ does not preserve a conformal class of an inner product when $n \ge 2$. But now if you have an inner product with vectors $u,w$ orthogonal, then you can find a linear transformation fixing $u$ and taking $w$ to $u+w$. Such a linear transformation does not preserve the conformal class.

Comment: I noticed that $ G $ has a subgroup $ SO_n $ which acts transitively and conformally (in fact by isometries). Do you know any example of a manifold $ M $ that admits a transitive action by a finite dimensional lie group but $ M $ does not admit any transitive action by conformal transformations?

Comment: No, I don't know such an example. I don't even know an example of a manifold admitting a transitive action but not admitting a transitive action by isometries.

Comment: The Klein bottle is such an example. The action is by the euclidean group $ E_2 $ and to see that there is no transitive action by isometries it is enough to note that Klein bottle is compact but there is no transitive action by a compact group since the commutator subgroup of the fundamental group is not finite. I believe in general there is a transitive action of $ E_n $ on the connected sum of two projective n spaces $ RP^n$. Also any nontrivial vector bundle cannot admit a transitive action by isometries. But for example $ E_2 $ acts transitively on the (open/ non compact) Moebius strip